# full or partial refund through PayPal standard in Magento

Tags: paypal, magento-1.7

I am using PayPal standard for order checkout from a Magento site. I am able to place a new order using PayPal, but  facing problem while doing online **partial-refund from PayPal**. **How to do full or partial refund through PayPal standard in Magento?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to make the change in Magento but there is a variable you post in each RefundTransaction call named `REFUNDTYPE` and you use that to set the kind of refund you want to process.

To do a partial refund you set: `REFUNDTYPE=Partial`

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I have tried that but now its giving me a error:Response:ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error.I am posting this to paypal-sandbox:METHOD=paypal_standard&VERSION=51.0&PWD=1370867958&USER=subhras_api1.mindfiresolutions.com&SIGNATURE=AhQHvKfH3szirJy.dfSi8ZaZzOvEAyIg325KUENGh9oXNk9YeNkRJZlR&TRANSACTIONID=64X40938D5153020R&REFUNDTYPE=Partial&CURRENCYCODE=GBP&AMT=5.00.Is any thing wrong in this?

Comment: "METHOD=paypal_standard" isn't a valid "METHOD" value. If you're trying to process a refund it should be like this: METHOD=RefundTransaction

Answer (score 0):

For Paypal-Sandbox account
    I want to do a partial-refund using the PayPal-Standard method in my Magento.

```
Created a new extension in local:
 -METHOD=RefundTransaction
 -VERSION=51.0
 -PWD=<your API password>
 -USER=<your API  Url>
 -SIGNATURE=<your API signature>
 -TRANSACTIONID = <order transaction id from paypal>
 -REFUNDTYPE=<Partial/full>
 -CURRENCYCODE=<currency code>
 -AMT=<amt to refund>

Post url:https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
Encaode the above post fields, used curl to post them

$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
$nvpreq = "METHOD=$_code&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr";

// Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

On calling the above it sends me a 'Success' response.
```